# Cross referencing results from query's

Tags: sql

I need to get an active count of patients who have been discharged in a given time frame, but here is the trick. In this table patients can show up more than once, our system uses an episode based system .

Like in (picture 1).

```
select 

p.patient_id,
p.episode_id,
p.case_status,
p.case_substatus,
p.episode_close_date

from patient p
```

[image]

I need no patients to show up in both of these query's.

```
select * from patient p
where p.case_status = 'a'
```

-

```
select * from patient p
where (p.episode_close_date between '2013-01-01 00:00:00.000' and '2013-06-01 00:00:00.000') and p.case_status = 'i'
```

I guess, what's the best way to do it, would be that that the highest p.episode_id = 'I'. Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with aggregation and a `having` clause.  The `having` clause counts the number of rows that match each condition -- and you want to set the values to `0` because you want both to return no rows:

```
select patient_id
from patient p
group by patient_id
having sum(case when p.case_status = 'a' then 1 else 0 end) = 0 and
       sum(case when (p.episode_close_date between '2013-01-01 00:00:00.000' and '2013-06-01 00:00:00.000') and
                     p.case_status = 'i'
                then 1 else 0
           end) = 0;
```

Basically, the logic in your first two queries in moved into the separate clauses of the `having`, to count the rows that match each condition.

EDIT:

Here is how you can see the last episode for each patient:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             max(episode_id) over (partition by patient_id) as maxei
      from patients p
     ) p
where episode_id = maxei;
```

You may also be able to use this with your logic, but I'm not sure about the interplay between the statuses and the dates in the query.

Comment: Hey Gordon thanks for the post, so this will go up to any episode number correct? It doesn't appear I can have it show additional information. Can I not add it in additional columns to view?

Comment: I think this is what I need. Let me work on this and see if I can get the results I need. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I am using this code in another query I'm working on and am running into an issue. Is there any way you could talk a look at it? Thank you so much for this code. I have used it all the time since you gave it to me a year ago. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27806899/including-null-results-after-join