# Including NULL results after join

Tags: sql-server-2005, join

I am trying to do a report which shows all payments we have received and for the report I have to show names of patients who pay, but this table also contains checks from payers (insurance companies) and after I do a join all of the payers are excluded. I have tried every join version I know left, right, outer, inner, and combinations of the two. SQL Server 2005.

*UPDATE*

The line that is causing the left join not to work is

```
select p.*, max(episode_id) over (partition by patient_id) as maxei from patient p
```

which I am using in the join. Our system uses an episodic system, so if a patient leaves and comes back they get a new episode. The payment table does not have an episode field though, so I used that line of code in the join to only show the current episode. Any idea how I can keep it only showing the current episode while not losing the fields without patient_id's? Examples of the fields without patients id's are shown in the second image.

```
select 

pay.patient_id,
p.lname + ', ' + p.fname as 'Name',
pay.source_type,
pay.instrument,
pay.doc_reference,
pay.instrument_date,
pay.payment_amount,
pay.user_id,
pay.entry_chron,
pay.payor_id


from payment pay
join (select p.*, max(episode_id) over (partition by patient_id) as maxei from patient p) p
on p.patient_id = pay.patient_id

where episode_id = maxei and (pay.instrument_date between '2014-11-01' and '2014-11-30')
order by pay.payment_amount
```

This is what the results look like for patients with some fields commented out for confidentiality. 
[image]

These are the fields that are being excluded
[image]

Comment: What's the exact probkem? Can you express it more briefly? Please show relevant (cut down) table schema, a few rows of data and desired output. The question as it stands is not very useful

Comment: What is the problem with `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: Sorry guys. I'll try and explain it better. So this table has payments from insurance companies (insurance companies are the payor_id field) and patients which is the patients field. When I join the patient_id field to the patient table it leaves the results out where patient_id is Null which are payments by the insurance companies.So basically the results that are shown in the second image are not being pulled by the code and what the code is pulling is the stuff in the first image. Does that make sense? It's hard to explain where I have to hide a lot of the fields. I need it to show both.

Comment: @bohemian the left join still isn't showing the results in the second image. That was the first thing I tried. The fact that I have to join it to the patient table to get names is making the join act a little wacky.

Comment: I found the line of code that is causing it to be omitted, but I need it for the report to not show tons of duplication. I added it in the main body under update.